# No data in showing custom variable

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I have created an app where I have used `GoogleAnalyticsTracker` to track events in google analytic.

Everything works fine here but when I want to track custom variable for a particular page than it doesn't show in my google analytic account. Although all other data i.e. pageView, Event are sent to my google analytic account except custom variable.

Why this happen is there anything missing in my code?

**Code that I have written:**

```java
GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    tracker.startNewSession("UA-xxxxxxx-1", this);

    tracker.setCustomVar(1, "Medium", "Mobile App",3);
    tracker.trackPageView("/testApplicationHomeScreen");
    tracker.dispatch();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are not navigating to he right place in your analytics account? (just guessing)

Comment: i go to Visitor->customVariable..is it right

Comment: its weird! Try always to use same custom variable: "1","Medium" ... try and try again.. maybe it works.. never do this: "1, "Medium", "bla" .. .then "1", "High" ,"blalba" .. you overwrite variables

Comment: i have use only tracker.setCustomVar(1, "Medium", "Mobile App",3); in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it takes time for google analytics to propagate through.  I've seen times of up to a day.  How long has it been since you've tried to track some analytics?

Comment: But the rest of the thing are shown..like pageView and event..so why no custom variable